# Delay ao atualizar arquivos via FTP com Filezilla

Tags: ftp, filezilla, hospedagem

estou enviando os arquivos atualizados para o servidor via FTP com Filezilla, é uma loja virtual, e os arquivos editados são simplesmente folhas de estilo, mas quando pressiono F5 para atualizar a página e ver as alterações, nada acontece, eu quero dizer, de imediato, às vezes a alteração demora minutos para acontecer, em outros sites hospedados em outro servidor isso não acontece, a plataforma que é usada é Opencart, alguém sabe algum jeito de resolver esse empecilho?

Comment: o mais provável é que seja cache do servidor. a locaweb  tem bastante esse problema.

Comment: tente fechar a conexao do fillezilla e abrir uma nova depois de alguns minutos

Comment: eu comecei a trabalhar com a loja agora (na hora/data deste comentário)

Comment: Imagino que vc quer dizer *"Em outros sites **hospedados no mesmo servidor** isso não acontece"*. Não tens nenhuma extensão de cache instalada nesse Opencart?

Comment: não. "em outros servidores"

Comment: Algo como Varnish Cache.

Comment: @GabrielSantos ??? não entendi

Comment: O Varnish Cache é um sistema de cache no servidor. Se estiver instalado, ao enviar arquivos via FTP, você vai perceber uma demora até que os arquivos apareçam atualizados de fato.

Comment: Na Locaweb tem um delay pra qualquer arquivo de imagem ou js que envie via FTP, isso é extremamente irritante quando se está fazendo algum teste online.

Answer (score 1):

Existem diversas extensões para o OpenCart que fazem cache. O ideal era saber qual delas você utiliza neste site/servidor, para verificar se há alguma configuração específica para ele reconhecer mais rápido os arquivos que foram atualizados.

Existe também extensões (por ex.: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3126&filter_search=cache&filter_license=0 ) que adicionam um botão de "limpar cache" à página do administrador. Assim, logo após o upload, você poderia limpar o cache e ver se resolve o teu problema.